# How to avoid pickling Celery task?

Tags: python, machine-learning, celery, pickle

My scenario is as follows: I have a large machine learning model, which is computed by a bunch of workers. In essence workers compute their own part of a model and then exchange with results in order to maintain globally consistent state of model.

So, every celery task computes it's own part of job. 
But this means, that tasks aren't stateless, and here is my trouble : if I say `some_task.delay( 123, 456 )`, in reality I'm **NOT** sending two integers here!

I'm sending whole state of task, which is pickled somewhere in Celery. This state is typically about 200 MB :-((

I know, that it's possible to select a decent serializer  in Celery, but my question is how **NOT** to pickle just ANY data, which could be in task.
How to pickle arguments of task *only*?
Here is a citation from celery/app/task.py:

```
  def __reduce__(self):
    # - tasks are pickled into the name of the task only, and the reciever
    # - simply grabs it from the local registry.
    # - in later versions the module of the task is also included,
    # - and the receiving side tries to import that module so that
    # - it will work even if the task has not been registered.
    mod = type(self).__module__
    mod = mod if mod and mod in sys.modules else None
    return (_unpickle_task_v2, (self.name, mod), None)
```

I simply don't want this to happen.
Is there a simple way around it, or I'm just forced to build my own Celery ( which is ugly to imagine)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the celery results backend for this. Use a separate data store.

While you could just use `Task.ignore_result` this would mean that you loose the ability to track the tasks status etc.

The best solution would be to use one storage engine (e.g. Redis) for your results backend. 
You should set up a separate storage engine (a separate instance of Redis, or maybe something like MongoDB, depending on your needs) to store the actual data.

In this way you can still see the status of your tasks but the large data sets do not affect the operation of celery.

Switching to the `JSON` serializer may reduce the serialization overhead, depending on the format of the data you generate . However it can't solve the underlying problem of putting too much data through the results backend.

The results backend can handle relatively small amounts of data - once you go over a certain limit you start to prevent the proper operation of its primary tasks - the communication of task status.

I would suggest updating your tasks so that they return a lightweight data structure containing useful metadata (to e.g. facilitate co-ordination between tasks), and storing the "real" data in a dedicated storage solution.

Comment: Thanks, scytale, but I already have the following definition in my code: app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://54.221.232.248', broker='redis://54.221.232.248'). But anyway, the task state is still pickled :-( I'm really confused

Comment: to simplify somewhat: `broker` is used to send messages (containing paramaters) to tasks. `backend` is used to return the results of the tasks. In your case you are using the same instance of redis for both. This runs the risk of message dispatching being overloaded by the large results. I would recommend a) using rabbitmq for broker, redis for backend b) not returning the large datasets from your tasks. Instead store them in a THIRD data store (a separate instance of redis maybe) and return only metadata from the tasks

Comment: Thanks again @scytale, but I don't want to store results in any external source, including Redis, because doing so will imply the network stress anyway. It's okay to store task's local data inside process memory and send only updated model state as a plain Python array ( once per N requests ), but how to disable pickling and storing state in external storage? Process memory is just fine for me

Comment: let's get a better idea of what your setup is and what problem you're trying to solve. how many machines are running celery? how many celery workers on each machine?

Comment: and can you confirm - you want to be able to directly exchange data between celery tasks without serialization and without using either the results backend or using an external data store. you want some way to share "process memory" between tasks, correct?

Comment: I'm doing data-parallel computation. I have one master server ( with Celery process daemonized on it ), which run only one task, named receive_all_local_updates. This task does what it says: it receives updates from each worker _in parameters_ ( long python array ) and patch some "global" array of parameters ( which is the output of my distributed learning process ). And also I have many ( about 100 ) workers, which compute parameters each on its own data shard. After each chunk of data is processed by worker, it calls master to merge results. These results passed in args of task

Comment: And yes, I have a setup of kind "one machine - one celery process in it", for simplicity. I will optimize this in future, but up to now the setup is exactly what was said.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't 100% understand your description. You have 1 server running 1 celery master process. You have 1 (or more ?) other server(s) running about 100 celery workers?

Comment: Yes, sure! One server running 1 master server and 100 servers running exactly one celery per server. I wanted to post updates from workers to master in arguments of a _delay_ function, hold intermediate results in memory at each worker and do not pickle whole task per call just to fulfill _kombu_ requirements to do so. And sorry me from posting a comment here, Stackoverflow says I'm disallowed to chat due to low reputation

Comment: I think part of the problem is that your description is really confusing. you say "I wanted to post updates from workers to master in arguments of a delay function" - that doesn't make sense in the context of how celery works - when you invoke `delay()` the master passes messages to the workers. these messages include the parameters. If the workers return something it is passed via the results backend. You cannot pass updates from workers to master in the arguments of the delay function.

Comment: is it the case that the paramaters that you pass to `some_task.delay()` are really really massive?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the ignore result from your task as it says in the docs:

> Task.**ignore_result**
>
> Don’t store task state. Note that this means you can’t use AsyncResult to check if the task is ready, or get its return value.

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo, but  actually need to use AsyncResult. This is crucial point of whole scheme . May be it's possible to split the task state to, say, fake "storable" part ( just to make AsyncResult work ) and my "usable" state of a task, which is not pickled per request? I have pretty high amount of requests, and it's impossible to move 200Mbs per request.

Answer (score -1):

That'd be a little offtop, but still.

What as I understood is happening here. You have several processes, which do heavy calculations in parallel with inter-process communications. So, instead of unsatisfying in your case celery you could:

- use [zmq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) for inter-process communications (to send only necessary data),
- use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for managing and running processes ([numprocs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) in particular will help with running multiple same workers).

While it will not require to write your own celery, some code will require to be written.

Comment: Thanks, @pavel_form, but the code was already written in this way and I have no option to make such a drastic changes at once